# rbenv reports different version of ruby than bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, rbenv

I'm trying to setup a rails app on a new machine and I'm having some trouble. I'm using a .ruby-version file to specify the ruby version we're using for the project which contains the following:

```
2.0.0-p643
```

Here's what happens when I try to look at what ruby versions I'm using

```
➜  app git:(master) ✗ rbenv versions
  system
* 2.0.0-p643 (set by /Users/stephen/workspace/prm/.ruby-version)
➜  app git:(master) ✗ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p643 (2015-02-25 revision 49749) [x86_64-darwin14.5.0]
```

So far so good. And yet when I try to install my dependencies with bundler, I get this:

```
➜  app git:(master) ✗ bundle
    Your Ruby version is 2.2.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.0.0
```

Why does rbenv report to me that I'm using the version I've intended by my ruby-version file yet when I try to run bundle it complains that I'm using the wrong version? I could see if it said that the patch level is causing problems because my gemfile just specifies 2.0.0 but why is it telling me that I'm using 2.2.3 when rbenv is telling me otherwise.

I tried uninstalling bundler, thinking that perhaps the bundler was the system bundler for some reason and that's what was causing the problem. Same problem.

For reference this is using the latest version of rbenv that was installed using homebrew on OSX Yosemite.

Comment: We need some more details to be able and help... What command are you using to run your script (i.e. `bundler exec my file.rb`)? does your script have a comment on the top (i.e. `#!/usr/bin/env ruby`) and what is it?

Comment: You're right I forgot to mention it's for a rails app! I'll edit the post.

Comment: Try using `rbenv shell 2.0.0-p643` and see if setting the ruby version for the whole shell (rather than the folder) helps. Also, try `bundle exec rails s` instead of `rails s` and see where that gets you. It might be a conflict between the local path settings and the global settings... let me know it it helps.

Comment: Just a sanity check: you don't have both `rbenv` and `rvm` on the same machine, do you?

Comment: @Drenmi that's a good question--I had been using rvm and was having problems with it so I removed it with `rvm implode` and by editing my .zshrc and then switched to rbenv. I just checked and it looks like rvm is in the path in several places still--could that matter?

Comment: @StephenMarianoCabrera: This is the only thing I can think of. Try doing `gem uninstall rvm`, and remove any `rvmrc` files on your system as well. I think `rvm implode` just removes all your rubies, not `rvm` itself.